# Triangulation and split of mesh via line mesh

Tags: 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, mesh, triangulation

I have two triangular mesh and I can compute the intersection of the meshes as line mesh; like this image;

[image]

I want to triangulate the non-triangle faces and split the mesh into two mesh over the line. Is there good and fast algorithm for this?

Comment: Intersection of a line segment with a triangle can only produce 1 triangle, 2 triangles, or a triangle + a convex quadrilateral, which can be trivially triangulated by adding a diagonal edge.

Comment: There may be more than one line segment on one triangle.

Comment: What about standard polygon triangulations, like ear clipping?